# newDateFormatter.string(from: ) is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I am formatting a randomly generated future date but it always returns nil even if the format of dateString is matching and has a value.

But if I try with only "(Date())" instead of newDate, it is successful.

```
let byDays = Int.random(in: 0...30)
var components = DateComponents()
components.day = byDays
let newDate = String(describing: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: Date()))

//give the current date output in string
let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
dateFormatterGet.isLenient = true
dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
dateFormatterGet.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

//describe the new format
guard let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: newDate) else {
    return ""
}

let newDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
newDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
let newStr = newDateFormatter.string(from: date)

print(newStr)
```

I want the date optional(2019-07-23 17:44:23 +0000) to be printed as Jul 23.

Comment: Never use `String(describing:)` for anything other than printing debug statements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the purpose of `String(describing: ...` You can use the date from the `Calendar` right away:

```
func randomFutureDate() -> String? {
    let day = Int.random(in: 0...30)
    var components = DateComponents()
    components.day = day
    guard let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: Date()) else {
        return nil
    }
    let newDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    newDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
    return newDateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```